# 'admin' is not a registered namespace in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I'm attempting to upgrade quite a large Django project to the newly released Django 1.4, and I'm having some issues when running `python manage.py test`.

Lots of the internal tests which passed in Django 1.3 are now failing, with really odd messages that I can't seem to fix. One that appears the most is:

```
NoReverseMatch: u'admin' is not a registered namespace
```

This is raised for the `django.contrib.auth` tests for password changing in particular (one of which is `test_password_change_fails_with_mismatched_passwords (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.ChangePasswordTest)`. The strange thing is, the namespace is registered correctly and the application functions just fine. I am importing admin in the "new" way:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

When I Google this error in particular, all I can find is people importing the admin URLs using the old scheme, and nothing relating to this issue at all.

I've tried removing apps from `INSTALLED_APPS` one by one, but the auth tests simply won't pass. Also, when I load a Python interpreter from `python manage.py shell` and execute `reverse('admin:index')` the URL resolves to `/admin/` with no errors. I've read through the code extensively, and can't see where this can be falling down.

As I mentioned earlier, this isn't the only error that's occurring. I'm also getting `AttributeError: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` from the `test_site_profile_not_available (django.contrib.auth.tests.models.ProfileTestCase)` test, even though `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is defined in my `settings.py` file. How can Django's own tests be failing like this?

Comment: There's something wrong in your code. The Django tests don't fail under normal circumstances. You just need to carefully inspect everything. I had a similar error, and it turned out to be related to an unbalanced parenthesis in one of my urlpatterns.

Comment: Did you end up finding out what happened? I honestly walked into something like this too and I'm not sure what happened. I ended up having to just not moving the admin template stuff to my own app dir.

Comment: I have this same error for some django 1.5 tests, like  test_middleware_disabled.  I've tried to reverse the order of TEMPLATE_LOADERS as suggested in the accepted answer, and I've removed my admin templates from my app's template dir (as suggested by Amir) but I still get the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, this was due to the order of the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` key in my settings file.

I had the following:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
)
```

which, somehow, caused the error when reversing admin URLs. Switching the two round solved the issue. I would love to know how this happens, as it isn't reproducible in a blank Django 1.4 project.

What *was* reproducible, however, was the `AttributeError` for `settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`. Turns out this is a bug in Django 1.4, which was filed on release day [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17966).

Comment: I haven't found one yet - but I'd love to know if there is a way it can be done. I was frustrated by the low priority given to this issue, as it prevents using TDD or Continuous Integration for testing code.

I tried to create a custom test runner which would skip out this test in particular, but couldn't get it working. The only solution I know if (which isn't ideal) is to only test your own apps. If you use `django-nose`, this is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

**Short Answer:** You have a copy of Django admin template files copied in on of your app's templates directory from an earlier version of Django, then you upgraded Django but didn't update (re-copy) those local templates.

**Long Answer:** The main cause of this problem is using an older version of Django admin template files (which are installed where django itself is installed, usually python's `site-packages` or `dist-packages` directory). There is a backward incompatible change in Django 1.5 about url template tag, in which the first parameter must be a string, from [Django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/):

> One deprecated feature worth noting is the shift to “new-style” url
>   tag. Prior to Django 1.3, syntax like {% url myview %} was interpreted
>   incorrectly (Django considered "myview" to be a literal name of a
>   view, not a template variable named myview). Django 1.3 and above
>   introduced the {% load url from future %} syntax to bring in the
>   corrected behavior where myview was seen as a variable.

So, the problem is you have a copy of admin's template files in one of your app's templates folder, which is coppied from an earlier version of Django. This is usually done for overriding default admin templates. Because of the backward incompatible change noted, these outdated template file can not load in a newer Django environment, and cause the strange error: `NoReverseMatch: u'admin' is not a registered namespace`.

Changing order of `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` entries will ignore the local admin templates modifications in favor of default templates file (because default Django templates are loaded by complete path with `filesystem.Loader`). If the modifications are needed (which is usually the case), you must update your local admin template files from your new Django installation templates and reapply your modifications on them.

**Note 1:** A similar situation is when local admin templates are newer than Django installation's default, which seems this is your case. Similarly, the better fix is to update all copies of admin templates.

**Note 2:** Another possibility of getting such error is when using virtualenv. For example, if you are running your project with a virtualenv but the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` entry for Django admin templates is to your global python installation, you may get this error.

Comment: Amazing answer! I wish I could upvote this multiple times because you deserve it.

Answer (score 5):

Try add namespace="admin" within the include method in the urls.py file.

ex: url(r'^admin/', include("someUrlpattern", namespace="admin"))

Answer (score 2):

The app_directories template loader loads templates from the INSTALLED_APPS template directory, while the filesystem loader loads them from the templates directory configured in your TEMPLATE_DIRS settings.

Switching the two of them makes a huge difference because if you have custom templates in your app it will not load if the app_directories is at the top. If the filesystem loader is at the top, django will look for a template in your template directory first before loading the default one from the installed_apps.

That's why it is not reproducible in a blank Django project. It will look for templates at the right places.

Comment: This question is about an error regarding the URLconf, not templates. That's why I was (and still am) perplexed about the fix.

Answer (score 0):

My solutuion was to upgrade django to the newest cersion:
pip install --upgrade django==1.6.1
before this, check your installed version:
pip freeze | grep Django
- I found that on release server there was an old version, upgrade solved this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message happen to me because my URLs conf had 2 `logout` URLs defined .

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 'logged_out.html'}, name='logout'),
]
```