# NoReverseMatch at /, u'opts|admin_urlname' is not a registered namespace Django 1.4.1

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

Django newbie here.  Following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls), I am trying the following to get a link to the admin site from the homepage of the public site I'm building:

```
{% load admin_urls %}
<p>Go to the <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'add' %}">admin</a>.</p>
```

I am getting the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
u'opts|admin_urlname' is not a registered namespace
```

I am including the URLs properly:

```
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

My [template loaders are in the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874192/admin-is-not-a-registered-namespace-in-django-1-4).

I've tried a few different variations on this, and they all throw namespace errors.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the above answers were helpful about the code I was calling, there is a *much* easier way.  I'm using this instead:

```
{% url 'admin:index' %}
```

This works for custom admin views as well, like:

```
{% url 'admin:myapp_mymodel_<keyword>' object.id %}
```

Where `keyword` is from the [named parameters listed here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) (i.e. `add`, `change`, `delete`).

Comment: This worked nicely for me but needed quotes (perhaps a Django change since this answer was posted): ``{% url 'admin:myproject_myapp_user_change' user.id %}``

Answer (score 5):

After 30 minutes with Daniel Roseman / Django docs in one screen and my code in the other, I come up with this simple solution:

In your `views.py`, add the opts context with the _meta of the model (that includes the required `app_label` and `model_name`):

```
class YourModelDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(YourModelDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["opts"] = YourModel._meta
        return context
```

In your templates:

```
{% url opts|admin_urlname:'change' object.pk %}
```

Where **change** can be any action in the [reverse admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly using the released 1.4 version, rather than the development version. As the [documentation for that version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) shows, you need to use `{% load url from future %}` before you can use that syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  First of all, what is up w/ the friggin Django documentation -- there are multiple versions of the same pages?!  The only difference btw. my link and yours is that one line, and there is no indication even in the 1.4 link about that change.  But back to the point, now I am getting `AttributeError at /, 'str' object has no attribute 'app_label'` -- ???

Comment: I can't understand your objection. Obviously, as changes are made to Django in subsequent versions over the years, there need to be new versions of the docs - I've no idea why you would find that strange.

Comment: Your comment spurred me to look closer at the page to see for the first time that nav in the lower-right to change the documentation version.  Well, glad to have finally noticed that, though it is awfully subtle.  Anyway, thoughts on that `AttributeError`?  ;-)

Comment: What are you passing as `opts`? Seems like you're passing a string, whereas the docs say it should be an object with `app_label` and `module_name` attributes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Please look at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890935/how-to-translate-an-app-template] if you have any idea please post your answer there **thanks**

Comment: Yes, it turns out, I was passing opts as a string -- misunderstood what the docs were saying about what opts is.