# Listing specific category first in Python

Tags: python, mysql, jinja2, werkzeug

I have a list of categories from DB as following and it works fine + sorted by ID.

```
{% for category in menu_categories|sort(attribute="id"):  %}    
<div>
    {{ category.name }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I just need one exception if `category='Pizza'` exist to list it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you, this should do it:

```
{% for category in menu_categories|sort(attribute="id"): %}
    {% if category.name == 'Pizza': %}
        <div> {{ category.name }} </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for category in menu_categories|sort(attribute="id"): %}
    {% if category.name != 'Pizza': %}
        <div> {{ category.name }} </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need entire list except only if category PIZZA exist to be listed first.

Comment: That's what this does; it will list the Pizza category first, then all those that aren't Pizza.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid please look at this question for a minute  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890935/how-to-translate-an-app-template]   if YOU can help me please post your answer there 

Thanks

Comment: I think using the sort filter to list the Pizza category first could be faster. Although that's just speculating.