# How to add link at top of django admin list

Tags: python, django

I want to do the following:

I want to add a "Refresh" link at the top of the django admin page for a model. How can I do that? I want when people click on Refresh they go to another page that gets data from Google analytics API.

How can I add a link at the top of the admin page for a model? Thanks!

What I tried:
I tried overriding the change_list template for the django admin, but that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding the change_list template is really your only choice. Did you get errors? or did your content not show up? The hierarchy of your templates directory is directly related to how/where Django looks for templates.

Double check the documentation on overriding admin templates. You may have made a simple mistake: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: I get the following error: u'admin' is not a registered namespace in Django 1.4

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874192/admin-is-not-a-registered-namespace-in-django-1-4 for a possible fix.